# How do you upload an image to Amazon S3 using wideimage

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using the [Amazon SDK for PHP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object) and [wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/doc/WideImage/WideImage_Image.html#methodresize).  I am resizing an image with wideimage and trying to then upload that resized image to Amazon S3.

```
$resized = $image->resize($width,$height);
```

upload

```
$response = $s3->create_object($myBucket, $newFilename, array(
    'fileUpload' => $resized, //this does not work          
));
```

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving the file to the server and then uploading the file from there.  If there is a better way then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stream wrapper and use WideImage's saveToFile method. There are many stream wrappers for S3, this is one example: https://github.com/jakajancar/S3StreamWrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save an image and then upload from there.

When you resize the image, you have to convert to a string. You can do that with WideImage class.

Example:

```
$image = WideImage::load($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']);
$resized = $image->resize(1024);
$data = $resized->asString('jpg');
```

And then when you're uploading on Amazon, you have to use the param 'body' instead of 'fileUpload'.

Example:

```
$response = $s3->create_object($myBucket, $newFilename, array(
'body' => $data,
```

));

I hope that helps.

Comment: This looks like a good alternative and would avoid having to store, upload and unlink.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out few things might help someone in making choice.

First of all, I think you better go with what you are trying to do first resize image over your server and then move it to Amazon because suppose if there is some kind of way to resize and upload image at same time on the fly then your script will perform slow because script will have to resize and save it to server which is far away destined. It would be minor if there are few images but can be a problem when it's huge resizing even on high speed bandwidth and as PHP will not be able to release its resources used for image resizing until it has not completely saved the target image.

Second that if you are using a CDN (Content Delivery Network) then CDN uses **PULL SERVER** technique means that we do not push static content to CDN server but when a user/client ask for static content then CDN first checks its entire servers and if not found then it asks our main server for that.

***Amazon S3** is not a true CDN*. S3 was designed for content storage. The correct Amazon service to use for content delivery is [**Amazon CloudFront**](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). And if we are saving files to any of our files to any storage server or CDN then that's called **PUSH SERVER**

A thorough article can be read on http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/11/timthumb-cdn-amazon-s3-good/. That's actually about TimThumb but worth a good knowledge.